# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in jquery call back function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I have very big trouble with `$.post()` callback. This function return some value, but when I look for its type (`back.type`) it returns "defined" and I have error loop that increase every second and it cause problems.

```
function upMessage() {
  var id = $(".id").val();
  var data = "id=" + id;
  $.post("ajax/upMessage.php", {
    id: id
  }, function(back) {
    back = back.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i <= (parseInt(back.length)) + 1; i++) {
      var backing = back[i];
      backing = backing.split("*");
      if (backing != "he," && backing != undefined && backing != "") {
        var id = backing[0];
        var oxu = backing[1];
        if (oxu == "he") {
          oxu = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\" style=\"color:#2B85DB;margin-right:-7px\"></i><i class=\"fa fa-check\" style=\"color:#2B85DB;\"></i>";
        } else {
          oxu = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\" style=\"margin-right:-7px\"></i><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>";
        }
        $("span#r" + id + ".i").html(oxu);
      }
    }
  });
}
setInterval(upMessage, 700);
```

I have error loop in page.
For example.
http://masters.az
login:leo
pass:12345

Comment: backing = backing.split("*"); - this is going to be an array but you treat it as string.

Comment: how can i convert it to string?

Comment: 1. Put split after your check if (backing != "he," && backing !=...
2. Avoid type changing in your code. "backing" was a string then it is an array. Use different variables.
3. Show error message you get.

Comment: oooooo thank youu. it works :) thanks so muchhh :) my brain was stopped since yesterday i couldn't find solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put split after your check `if (backing != "he," && backing !=...`
2. Avoid type changing in your code. "**backing**" was a **string** then it is
   an **array**. Use different variables.
3. Show error message you get.